# Send mail with mapi in jython

Tags: java, python, winapi, jython, mapi

I am trying to use `pywin` in a  `jython` application for sending emails w/ attachments with outlook.

Pywin needs a win32 enviroment, but since we are in java and the function sys.platform returns "java1.6", everything does not work properly.

Should I use `JMapi` instead of `pywin`? If the answer is positive, where could I find some examples? Thank you.

sorry for the edit:
We are using `python 2.5`, `Java 1.6`, and the O/S is `Windows XP SP 3`.

Ooops, i am a moron . I cannot use smtplib, because the users want to look the emails in outlook before sending them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search provided [this](http://www.jython.org/docs/_sources/library/email-examples.txt) and [this](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/smtplib.html)... I don't think these examples are pywin or JMapi specific though...

Comment: Ooops, i am a moron . I cannot use smtplib, because the users want to look the emails in outlook before sending them. And smtplib sends the email without passing from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `mailto:` hyperlink and the [Desktop.mail(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29) method to invoke the right e-mail editor would be what you need then. According to [Wikiepdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) the URL scheme allows you to add subjects body etc..